# Linked list only prints out the last added member. What could be the mistake?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm having a problem with a one way linked list. I'm trying to add elements to the end of the list(I guess it's FIFO arrangement) inside of a function (not passing elements one by one from the main function) so my idea was to save the position of the head pointer and create another pointer which would change positions every time I added an element.

The problem is that the head pointer's value also changes when I add a new element and I'm not sure why, because the only time I changed anything in regards to the head pointer is when I added the first element to the list. Then created the "current" pointer which I assigned to the head pointer and used from then on to add all other elements, but when I tried printing the head pointer value in each iteration of the while loop, it printed the last entered value (the value I wanted to assign to "current", not head).

When I try to print out the whole list, it only prints out the last element over and over.

Here's the code I've written:

```
typedef struct node NODE;
typedef struct node* PNODE;


struct node {
    int info;
    PNODE next;
};


void addToEnd(PNODE *head) {
    PNODE newN = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    
    int num = 0;
    printf("Type in the numbers. The loop ends when you type in -1.\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    getchar();
    newN->info = num;
    newN->next = NULL;
    (*head) = newN;
    PNODE current = *head;
    while(1) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        getchar();
        if (num == -1) {
            break;
        }

        newN->info = num;
        newN->next = NULL;

            
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            current->next = newN;
            current = current->next;
        }
            
        
    }


    current = (*head);

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->info);
        current = current->next;
    }
}


main() {
    PNODE head = NULL;
    addToEnd(&head);
    
}
```

Comment: Why did you add the C++ tag when the code is C?

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef (*i.e.* your `PNODE`) unless you intend values to be opaque.  It is extremely poor style, tending more to confuse than to help.

Comment: You only ever have one node. One `malloc` means one node. You are just writing to that one node over and over again. Suggest you search for linked list examples (there are a bazillion of them) and see how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the head pointer's value also changes when I add a new element and I'm not sure why, because the only time I changed anything in regards to the head pointer is when I added the first element to the list.

By "the head node's value" I take you to mean `(*head)->info` (as opposed to `*head`).

It is true that you assign a value to `*head` only once, but you update the value of `(*head)->info` multiple times, as a result of `*head`, `newN`, and `current` all having the same (pointer) value.  Observe:

> ```
>     (*head) = newN;
>     PNODE current = *head;
> ```

... `*head` is assigned the value of `newN` and `current` is assigned the value of `*head`; now these are all the same.  Then ...

> ```
>         newN->info = num;
>         newN->next = NULL;
> ```

... `current`, `newN`, and `*head` are all still the same, so this sets the `info` and `next` members of the node to which they all point.  Then, because `current == newN`, we know that `current->next == newN->next`, which was just set to `NULL`, so this is always executed:

> ```
>         if (current->next == NULL) {
>             current->next = newN;
>             current = current->next;
> ```

Moreover, because `current` and `newN` (and `*head`) are still equal, `current->next = newN` is equivalent to `current->next = current`, and of course, after that, `current = current->next` does not change the value of `current` or make it unequal to `*head` or `newN`.  The three remain the same at all times throughout the input loop.

After that, of course ...

> ```
>     current = (*head);
> ```

... still leaves the three pointers all equal to each other. If at least one number was entered during the input loop then we also have `current->next == current`, so the print loop will print the last value entered over and over, until you kill the program.

In short, it's pretty much all wrong.

If you want to add elements to a list such that each one is appended at the end, then a reasonable way to proceed is this:

1. PREPARATION

   1. Create a dummy `NODE` and assign `*phead` as the value of its `next` pointer.  (Just declare a `NODE` normally; this one doesn't need to be dynamically allocated.)
   2. Initialize `current` to point to the dummy node (`current = &dummy`).
   3. Use a loop to advance `current` to point to the last node in the list (it will continue to point to `dummy` if the list is initially empty).
2. INPUT

   1. Attempt to read a value. Break from the loop if none is presented; otherwise ...
   2. Allocate a new `NODE`.
   3. Assign the newly read value to the new node.
   4. Update `current->next` to point to the new node.
   5. Update `current` to point to the new node. (Do not do this before step 4!)
   6. Go back to INPUT.1.
3. FINISHING UP

   1. After loop termination, `current` points to the last node added.  Set `current->next` to `NULL` to mark the end of the list.
   2. Set `*head = dummy->next`.  If the list was initially empty and at least one value was added, then this will assign `*head` to point to the head node.  Otherwise, it will just copy the original value of `*head` back into it (see step PREPARATION.1).